# AudioKit parameters range

Tags: swift, audiokit

I am new to AudioKit, newish to Swift to be honest.
I cannot find in the documentation any reference to the range of many or any of the .notation parameters in the synths.

So for instance obviously frequencyCutOff is generally in Hz so the range is 0 - 30k or whatever. I'm assuming most have a 0-1 range as standard. There are many others which I would have thought will have min and max values that may be more defined.

Envelopes for instance. ADSR. Are they supposed to be in seconds? if so can I have a release time of 1000s ?! The docs are a little vague to me or am I missing something. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not in the AudioKit team, but as I use daily AudioKit, I can answer you.

Yes you are right, range of many parameters are not clearly specified in the docs.

But you can find them by searching in the [AudioKit Playgrounds examples](https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/).
Most of the AudioKit objects are covered here and you will find many info about parameters range.
Alternatively, you can also have a look in the AudioKit Xcode project exemples.

About ADSR, yes value is seconds for Attack, Decay and Release.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Yes its a shame their docs aren't a bit more detailed. I don't suppose you can explain the "taper" parameter in this: let sliderOne = AKSlider(property: "FM CARRIER X",
                                 value: FMSynth.carrierMultiplier,
                                 range: 0 ... 30,
                                 
                                 taper: 4,
                                 format: "%1.0f"